# What is a good way to read in text?

Tags: perl, stdin, readline

In my sms-script I read in the text to send with this subroutine:

```
my $input = input( "Enter the input: " );

sub input {
    my $arg = shift;
    print $arg if $arg;
    print "\n ";
    chomp( my $in = <> );
    return $in;
}
```

This way I can correct errors only through canceling all until I reach the error and this only in the last line. 
Is there a better way to read in my text?

Comment: -1 You only read one line of input. There is no attempt to detect and/or correct any errors in the code you posted.

Comment: I thought there would be some module. I have written now a validate_input-routine but maybe I like more a “system( ‘vim’, $tempfile ) / read in $tempfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "normal" way to read input:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# ...

while (my $input = <>)
{
    chomp $input;
    handle_error($input), next unless validate($input);

    # do something else with $input...    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop inside your `input` subroutine, e.g.

```
my $is_valid = 0;
my $input; 

while (!$is_valid) {   
    print "Enter something: ";  
    $input = <>;  
    $is_valid = validate_input($input);
}
```